# MySQL - Count and CASE WHEN

Tags: mysql

My google and stockoverflow searches failed me so need your help. I have a below table

```
+------+------+------+------------+
| id   | Loc  | MEL  | COUNT(MEL) |
+------+------+------+------------+
|    1 | AAA  | A    |          1 |
|    2 | BBB  | B    |          1 |
|    3 | CCC  | C    |          1 |
|    4 | AAA  | D    |          1 |
|    5 | AAA  | A    |          1 |
|    6 | BBB  | B    |          1 |
|    7 | BBB  | C    |          1 |
|    8 | AAA  | D    |          1 |
+------+------+------+------------+
```

I want to transform it to the following table:

```
+------+------+------+------+
| MEL  | AAA  | BBB  | CCC  |
+------+------+------+------+
| A    |  2   |      |      |
| B    |      |   2  |      |
| C    |      |   1  |   1  |
| D    |  2   |      |   1  |
+------+------+------+------+
```

All conbinations of COUNT and CASE WHEN did not work?

Code to get the below tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders
(
id INT,
Loc char(255),
MEL char (10))

insert into Orders values 
(1,   "AAA", "A"),
(2,   "BBB", "B"),
(3,   "CCC", "C"),
(4,   "AAA", "D"),
(5,   "AAA", "A"),
(6,   "BBB", "B"),
(7,   "BBB", "C"),
(8,   "AAA", "D");
```

Comment: try googling or searching PIVOT

Comment: Alternatively, consider handling issues of data display in application code.

Comment: I have this code but as I had said before it did not work. `SELECT
    MEL,
    COUNT(Loc = 'AAA')AS 'AAA',
    COUNT(Loc = 'BBB')AS 'BBB',
    COUNT(Loc = 'CCC')AS 'CCC',
    COUNT(Loc = 'DDD')AS 'DDD'
FROM ORDERS GROUP BY MEL;`

Comment: You probably need conditional aggregation and dynamic sql.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select mel, 
sum(Loc="AAA") AS AAA, 
sum(Loc="BBB") AS BBB /* and so on */
from Orders group by mel;
```

You need to use `sum` instead of `count`, because the boolean expression returns 0 or 1. `count` doesn't care about that, it just counts, whether it's 0 or 1 doesn't matter.